# ?:0: attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'fileSize' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, adobe

How to resolved error or possible ways to resolved it?

Guys, i've developed plugin using Lua language which can be integrate or run from Adobe's LightRoom Classic. Currently i need to upload or send a file to server but i can not. Everytime i called the POST API which is multipart/form-data error popup "**?:0: attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'fileSize' (a nil value)**". Not even API is being called this error pops up before API call. after debug I can assure the possible issue is in creating **mimeChunks** with file type.

I have developed the code like below, can any one help me out with suggestions so that i can able to resolved issue?

```
local filePath = assert("C:\Users\Ankit\Desktop\Hangman.PNG")
local fileName = LrPathUtils.leafName(filePath)

local mimeChunks = {}
mimeChunks[#mimeChunks + 1] = {
  name = 'api_sig',
  value = "test value"
}
mimeChunks[#mimeChunks + 1] = {
  name = "file",
  filePath = filePath,
  fileName = fileName,
  contentType = "application/octet-stream"
}

local postUrl = "API endpoint"
local result, hdrs = LrHttp.postMultipart(postUrl, mimeChunks)
if result then
  LrDialogs.message("Form Values", result)
else
  LrDialogs.message("Form Values", "API issue")
end
```

Comment: Try escaping backslashes in strings.

Comment: Yes right, That option works here. That was the issue. Thanks @lhf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually image or file path itself cause the issue, there are no such indications or articles related to this functionality, but yes "**add-on backslash**" will work out for sure. Kindly review the below code for more detailed bifurcation which pass dynamic selected file or image path.

```
local function uploadFile(filePath)
    local fileName = LrPathUtils.leafName( filePath )
    local mimeChunks = {}
    mimeChunks[ #mimeChunks + 1 ] = { name = 'api_sig', value = "test value"}
    mimeChunks[#mimeChunks + 1] = {
        name = "file",
        filePath = filePath,
        fileName = fileName,
        contentType = "image/jpeg"  --multipart/form-data  --application/octet-stream
    }
    import "LrTasks".startAsyncTask( 
        function()
            local postUrl = "http://cms.local.com/api/v1/upload"
            local result, hdrs = LrHttp.postMultipart(postUrl, mimeChunks)
            if result then
                LrDialogs.message("Image uploaded.", result)
            else
                LrDialogs.message("Error", "API issue")
            end
        end
    )
end
```

Above **uploadFile** method will automatically call the API and post form-data collection. Below code is for call **uploadFile** function which select all the images from catalog.

```
for p, photo in ipairs(LrApplication.activeCatalog()) do
    uploadFile(assert(photo:getRawMetadata('path')));
end
```

Above code will help you out the selection of categlog with Adobe's LightRoom Plugin.